# Does decreasing transmit power of wireless router decrease the bandwidth?

Tags: wireless-router, speed

I have a very simple wireless router (without a lot of settings to change). I want to limit the speed for the devices that connect directly to my router via WiFi -- so that my PC which is connected to the router directly via network cable can get the best speed.

I have a setting `transmit power` that was `100%`. If I decrease that, can I get the effect I am after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transmit power just adjusts the output amplitude of the signal, it does not change the frequency.

This adjusts how far the signal will travel, not the amount of data in the signal.

Answer (score 1):

wrong

I stick our router which is downstairs, down to just 2mhz, power output this limits the transmission speed from 80-100% to just 13mbps which is enough for the kids

no more work conference calls interrupted because a nintendo switch is downloading games

IF its "dad the wifi is slow" then i question what they have done, so they pause downloads for another time or heaven forbid go outside

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).